# Why document.documentElement.clientHeight is different from site to site?

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I am trying to find out what is my viewport size in my Chrome browser. So, I go to a particular page, for example stackoverflow.com and open the console and type:

`document.documentElement.clientHeight` which outputs **597**
`document.documentElement.clientWidth` which outputs **1229**

Then I visit another page, for example google.com. With the same browser (I just open a new tab):

`document.documentElement.clientHeight` which outputs **525**
`document.documentElement.clientWidth` which outputs **1093**

I am wondering why this would happen? Isn't this supposed to give me the viewport? Or in other words, the size of the page that I am seeing (without scrolling)?

I took two screenshots (using Firefox happens the same):

http://prntscr.com/20s6k9
http://prntscr.com/20s6vt

Comment: Unable to reproduce this. I get 1007 at several sites when using `document.documentElement.clientWidth`.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm using Chrome and Ubuntu 12.04. The values vary for almost every page :S

Comment: I opened google chromes console in separate window. It gives me same result in terms of height and width. I hope it will help. PS. I am using Chrome in MAC. Your are not using Chrome. Your are using Mozilla Firefox according your screenshot. In Mac, Everything is working fine even with Mozilla Firefox. Tomorrow I can check in my ubuntu pc at work.

Comment: @TravisJ I added two screenshots.

Comment: Is it something to do with margins/padding of the page body?

Comment: I am using windows 7 with two displays, when I open Chrome over the extend display and open differents tabs I get diferents Heights, but when I do the same over the main monitor I get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are in CSS pixels. Judging by the screenshots you have different zoom settings for the pages, which means the viewport height and width are different numbers of CSS pixels.

Note that the aspect ratio for both pages is the same 3.16:1.

Comment: I haven't changed the zoom. Is this something that the page itself can do?

Comment: Not that I know of, but zooms are site specific and can be preserved between browser sessions. CTRL-0 will reset the zoom on any page.

Comment: Wow. That might be it!!

Comment: @HommerSmith yes you can: el.style.zoom = 1.5; el.style.MozTransform = 'scale(1.5)'; el.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(1.5)';

Comment: This is confirmed. @HommerSmith: It looks like you've probably Ctrl + Scroll Wheeled or otherwise zoomed in accidentally. If you run the command, then zoom in, and run it again, you'll notice that the number of pixels goes down as you zoom in.